# Session Url for multipart upload

Tags: pre-signed-url, google-cloud-storage, signed-url, multipart-upload, resumable-upload

I am getting data from a video/screen recording. Since the data is in chunks of 1 second, I have implemented the multi part upload where i hit python backend for signed url. But this is leading to a lot of latency as getting url is becoming a bottleneck. How can i use a multipart upload with session url so that i do not have to generate signed url again and again. I did try resumable upload also but then i have to upload atleast in multiples of 256 KB.

I have tried
multipart upload
resumable upload
streaming data
but not able to improve efficiency in upload

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.